# Is this functional linear?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions

I know it's trivial, but is this functional not linear?

$\phi:\mathbb{R}[X]\ni p \rightarrow p(0)p \in \mathbb{R}[X]$

$$\phi(p+q)=(p+q)(0)\cdot(p+q)=(p(0)+q(0))\cdot(p+q)\ne\phi(p)+\phi(q)$$

Comment: Yes, it is not linear

Comment: It may be ridiculous question, but can non-linear operator be continuous?

Comment: I think that, depending on the topology on the relevant spaces, this is possible.

Comment: For example there are a lot of "operators" $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that are not linear wrt. any vectorspace structure on $\mathbb{R}$ but are still continuous, e.g. $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Maybe it will be even more ridiculous question - can we find norm of operator that is not continuous or even non-linear?

Comment: Yes, if the relevant spaces admit a norm (this might sound circular). To expand on Jeppe's comment, consider the 'operator' sending $x\mapsto x+1$. This is clearly non-linear, continuous and in the supremum-norm its norm is $1$.

Comment: Why supremum norm is 1?

Comment: Because I thought that $\frac{|x+1|}{|x|}$ has lowest upper bound $1$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$. However, I believe now I was wrong: for $|x| <1$, this fraction blows up, so the operator is unbounded. If we define it on a smaller domain than $\mathbb{R}$, it will of course still work, take for example $x>2$.

Comment: I see now, thank you.